# Trying to get a SQL query to retrieve data by month instead of by day

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query:

```sql
Select * from random_table where dt >= date('12/1/2022')
```

The problem with this is its giving me daily data. Can I adjust this code and add `date_trunc` to aggregate by month, if so, how would i do that?

I haven't tried anything yet as I am a noob when it comes to SQL

Comment: you don't have any aggregation or grouping in your query

Comment: date('12/1/2022') is  NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `DATE_FORMAT`, and select your aggregation function

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m'), SUM(...)
FROM random_table
where dt >= date('12/1/2022')
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y')` to convert your string to date, and `DATE_FORMAT` to compare with the month needed

```
select *
from random_table
where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m') = '2022-12';
```

To show month instead of day :

```
Select id, name, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m') as month
from random_table
where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m') = '2022-12';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gnCrbmhH)